# Probability of choosing a partner

Tags: probability

My problem is:
There are 10 boy and 10 girl and we choose couples(boy-girl) randomly.
We know 3 guys (Aladar,Bela,Csaba) and 3 girls (Aranka,Bori,Cecilia).
What is the probability that Aladar is not in a pair with Aranka, Bori nor Cecilia and Bela in not in a pair with Bori and Cecilia and Csaba is not in a pair with Cecilia.
So it is restricted to make pairs where any of the listed couples dance together.

[image]

I think maybe I should calculate the probability that **'a'** choose **'a' or 'b' or 'c'**, it's 3/10. And I should add the probability that **'b'** choose **'b' or 'c'** and **'c'** choose **'c'**, these are 2/10 and 1/10. If I add them together I get 6/10. There I would subtract the probability of the cases I counted multiple times. These are *P(a->b|b->b), P(a->c|b->c), P(a->c|c->c), P(b->c|c->c)* and all these probabilities are *1/100* so I subtract all of them from *60/100* to get *56/100*. This is the opposite of the probability I search for so the solution is *44/100*. That's my idea, but it can be wrong.

I'm looking forward your answers!

Andrew

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?

Comment: I've just got an idea, but I don't know if it is a right one.

Comment: Sorry, Daniel McLaury - it was an accident:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your plan of attack *can* work if you're very careful to correct appropriately for double-counted cases, and then re-correct for cases you've corrected for twice, etc.

Your *implementation* of it seems to be wrong, though, because you're getting a different answer from the one I'm getting by a simpler method, namely just to count all of the **valid** matchings:

How many ways is there to choose a partner for Aladar? *Once Aladar has a partner*, how many ways to choose a partner for Bela? Once the the first two boys have partners, how many for Csaba to choose among?

Multiply, and then compare this to the number of ways there are to choose partners *without* the restrictions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I know what was wrong with my answer, but yours is more simple.